# fetch function in javascript looping twice

Tags: javascript, django

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    // Use buttons to toggle between views
    document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
    document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
    document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
    document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);

    // By default, load the inbox
    load_mailbox('inbox');

    document.querySelector('#compose-form').onsubmit = () => {
        fetch('/emails', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                recipients: document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value,
                subject: document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value,
                body: document.querySelector('#compose-body').value
            })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                // Print result
                console.log(result);
            });
        // localStorage.clear();
        load_mailbox('sent');
    }
});
```

```
function load_mailbox(mailbox) {

    // Show the mailbox and hide other views
    document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

    // Show the mailbox name
    document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;


    fetch('/emails/sent')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(emails => {
            // Print emails
            console.log("Hello, world!");

            // ... do something else with emails ...
        });
}
```

**
corresponding api where fetch request is being made
**

```
@login_required
def mailbox(request, mailbox):

    # Filter emails returned based on mailbox
    if mailbox == "inbox":
        emails = Email.objects.filter(
            user=request.user, recipients=request.user, archived=False
        )
    elif mailbox == "sent":
        emails = Email.objects.filter(
            user=request.user, sender=request.user
        )
    elif mailbox == "archive":
        emails = Email.objects.filter(
            user=request.user, recipients=request.user, archived=True
        )
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Invalid mailbox."}, status=400)

    # Return emails in reverse chronologial order
    emails = emails.order_by("-timestamp").all()
    print(request.user)
    for email in emails:
        print(email)
    return JsonResponse([email.serialize() for email in emails], safe=False)
```

Actually, fetch function loops twice and "Hello, world!" is printed twice in console, so emails when fetched also get displayed twice. Please tell me why fetch request is called twice on backend. Please feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: Where do you call ```load_mailbox```?

Comment: I have added the remaining code.